# How do I elevate vbs to delete a Registry key

Tags: vbscript, registry

This is the faulty code

```
WshShell.RegDelete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\cFos\test\tvalue"
```

This is my error
Error: Unable to remove registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\test".
Code: 800070005
Source:  WshShell.RegDelete

I gather that I need to disable UAC in Win Vista/7/8 but I was wondering if there is a way to directly run the .vbs file as administrator. Because I need to distribute it and people might not like disabling their UAC and some might even think this is malicious if I give an explicit instruction to pull down their defense

Comment: You don't disable UAC. You ask people with admin privileges to run the VBScript. If you need administrative rights, you should ask for them. If you could do it without permission it wouldn't be much in the way of security, right?

Comment: Right-click -> "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @CodyGray, the context option only appears for executable files.  That doesn't work for script files.

Comment: When the error occured, let the script re-run itself using `RUNAS.EXE` program to execute `CSCRIPT.EXE` as Administrator. Add a *marker* parameter for the script to avoid infinite loop in case the error occured even when run using Administrator.

Comment: @Jay Sorry but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new shortcut file using below command line.

```
runas /profile /user:administrator cscript myscript.vbs
```

or...

```
runas /profile /user:administrator cscript "C:\Script Collection\My Script.vbs"
```

You can then simply double click the shortcut file to execute the script using Administrator account.

The shortcut will prompt for Administrator password each time. If you want it to fully automate it, use below command line instead.

```
runas /profile /savecred /user:administrator cscript myscript.vbs
```

It will prompt for the password, but only once. The next time you run it, it will not prompt it again.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Start Menu and type `cmd`.  When Command Prompt appears, right-click it and choose Run as Administrator.  You can run your script from the elevated command prompt with either cscript.exe or wscript.exe.

To run the script from a shortcut, right-click the desktop and choose New > Shortcut.  It will prompt you for the location of the program.  Type the following:

runas /noprofile /savecred /user:**localmachinename**\administrator cscript.exe "**C:\path\to\script.vbs**"

Click Next.  Enter whatever name you like for your shortcut and then click Finish.

Comment: I want the script to delete the registry key on double click. Is it not possible to achieve it?