# Enable system protection using visual basic script on windows 8/10

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi, system-restore

I am trying to enable system protection using following visual basic script on windows 10. But it gives an error "access denied". I have searched microsoft documentation about WMI classes and it feels like that following code is perfectly fine for windows 7 or xp but not for windows 10 and after spending a lot of time while looking for documentation on microsoft's website I have not been able to find any clue of how to do this.

Note: I am looking for a visual basic script ony that enables protection on windows 10 if it is not.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default")

Set objItem = objWMIService.Get("SystemRestore")
errResults = objItem.Enable("D:\")

'Inform User that the task is done.
Mybox = MsgBox("System Restore is now enabled on "& strComputer &""  & 
vbCRLF ,vbOkOnly,"System Restore Enabled")
```

Comment: I have set user account control settings to "Never notify".

Comment: You'll still need to "run as administrator" in order for the script to work.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36458651/886887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11980651/886887).

Comment: I have tried that but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it figured. The following code successfully enables system protection in windows 10.

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim  oSR
Set oSR = GetObject("winmgmts:
{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!root/default:SystemRestore")
oSR.Enable("D:" & "\")
```